# Getting different image after saving as BLOB in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I've just saved an image (PNG, 200x209)

```
$img = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("image.png")));
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (img) VALUES ('$img') WHERE userid = 10";
mysql_query($sql);
```

(img has a MEDIUMBLOB type)

then trying to obtain it (show.php):

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

$sql = "SELECT img FROM table WHERE userid = 10 LIMIT 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $image = base64_decode($row['img']);
}

echo $image;
```

when requesting **show.php** it gives almost the same image, but with another dimension: 136x94 =)

Why that happens?

Comment: shouldn't you set content type as PNG?

Comment: You're using a blob field. There's **NO** reason to be doing base64/chunking. Blobs are `BINARY LARGE OBJECT` and can directly handle the .png file as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you **save the image as is**. The **BLOB datatype of MySQL is specially used for binary data**. And this image is a binary file. And remove base64 encodings. It just increases the data size.

In the code you are saving png image but outputting a jpeg. Both content type should be same.

So insert code would be something like this,

```
$img = file_get_contents("image.png");
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (img) VALUES ('$img') WHERE userid = 10";
mysql_query($sql);
```

And show it as

```
header("Content-type: image/png");

$sql = "SELECT img FROM table WHERE userid = 10 LIMIT 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
echo mysql_result($res, 0);
```